# Displaying ActivityIndicator immediately

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiactivityindicatorview

I know how to animate,display the Activity Indicator.
But I want to know how to immediately show the Activity Indicator.

Now When I am click the button it will load another view after 5 or many seconds. Clicking that button is loading a subview. When that Button Click method is called, it will call more than 7 methods after that and then it will load the subview. But the ActivityIndicator is displayed only after it complete executing all the 7 methods.

What I am trying to do is , I want to display the ActivityIndicator immediately after that Button Click method.

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you perform your massive calculations (or loading from the internet?) on the main thread, but all the view mutation operations are not called immediately — on the start of the runloop the framework creates a new implicit Core Animation transaction, then it collects all the information about views' mutations, then *commits the transaction on the end of the runloop*. By blocking the main thread you are not allowing the transaction to commit and start your indicator's animation.

You can read about this architecture in the documentation: [Core Animation Programming Guide: Transactions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Transactions.html).

There are three options:

1. *(Preferred)* Perform your operations on the background.
2. Link your binary against `QuartzCore.framework`, then `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and call `[CATransaction commit]` after your `startAnimating` call. This way you commit the *implicit* transaction.
3. Create your own *explicit* `CATransaction`.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction)button_click{

..
..
..

[self performSelector:@selector(afterDelay) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
}

-(void)afterDelay{

YOUR_Code 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have put the code to display or unhide the `activityIndicator` but it is not shown you have to use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method for doing any thing after unhide or displaying the `activityIndicator` with the delay of 0.001 will show the indicator immediately after clicking the button

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score -1):

If your are talking about the system activity indicator, use this :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] performSelector:@selector(setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES ] afterDelay:0.0];
```